# Crystal Reports .NET - Multiple Subreports - Table [name] could not be found

Tags: .net, crystal-reports

Using VB.NET on VS2008.

I'm having trouble getting this report to work when using different data tables for some subreports. The thing that throws me off the most is that if I SetDataSource only once I don't get any errors but if I use two or more tables from the xsd the "Table [name] could not be found" error shows up.

This works (commenting one)

```
'objReport.Subreports.Item("rptDailySummaryContractTracking").SetDataSource(dsResult.Tables("dtDailySummaryContractTracking"))
objReport.Subreports.Item("rptDailySummaryDeposits").SetDataSource(dsResult.Tables("dtDailySummaryDeposits"))
```

This also works (commenting the other)

```
objReport.Subreports.Item("rptDailySummaryContractTracking").SetDataSource(dsResult.Tables("dtDailySummaryContractTracking"))
'objReport.Subreports.Item("rptDailySummaryDeposits").SetDataSource(dsResult.Tables("dtDailySummaryDeposits"))
```

But this doesn't

```
objReport.Subreports.Item("rptDailySummaryContractTracking").SetDataSource(dsResult.Tables("dtDailySummaryContractTracking"))
objReport.Subreports.Item("rptDailySummaryDeposits").SetDataSource(dsResult.Tables("dtDailySummaryDeposits"))
```

Any Ideas? I've looked and looked but can't find the reason it's not working.

Thanks in advance!Blockquote